# svnadmin hotcopy fails while restoring

Tags: linux, repository, subversion

I am trying to restore a svn repo using hotcopy method. While doing the same, I am getting below error :

```
svnadmin: E200030: sqlite[S11]: database disk image is malformed
svnadmin: E200042: Additional errors:
svnadmin: E200030: sqlite[S11]: database disk image is malformed
```

Any idea how to deal with this error?

Comment: Restore db from backup.

Comment: I thought svadmin hotcopy will take db backup as well. No?

Answer (score 0):

Doing hotcopy of DB files/structures often does not go well, depending on the DB technology, and especially when the hotcopy was done in the middle of a change.

Often you want to make sure the integrity of the DB is guaranteed, you either have a backup solution where the vendor/maker/author certifies it is application aware and capable of doing hotcopy, or on the other hand, you have to keep dumps of the DB.

An alternate solution that might not be so appealing is to stop the DB operations/shutdown it while it is being copied. But then you cannot call it a hotcopy anymore.

Comment: Thanks Rui for the response. 
What I am trying to achieve here is basically move svn repos to another svn host which is running on higher svn version. 
I tested the restoration using svn hotcopy multiple times and it all finished successfully. But on the cutover date, when I took fresh copy using hotcopy method and tried restoring, it failed with above error.
My repo is about 150G size which takes a lot of time to finish the backup process as well.
Please advise

Comment: I am more into MySQL/SQL databases. Better wait if someone has a better idea. Would you be able to define a better worded scope on your question? It seems a bit broad/vague.